# dplyr::filter() behavior unexpected with NAs

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data with the following two columns:

- `location_country` : alpha-2 code (e.g., "US")
- `location_admin_level_1`: administrative level 1 (for 'US' should be 2 characters)

In one step, I `filter()` out the `location_admin_level_1` where the number of characters is grater than 2:

```r
librayr(dplyr)

data %>%
    filter(location_country == "US",
           nchar(location_admin_level_1) > 2)
```

... which works properly.

However, when I try to filter these *out* (i.e., get the rest of the data), it returns a lesser number of rows than it should:

```r
# Does not behave as expected
data %>%
    filter(!(location_country == "US" & nchar(location_admin_level_1) > 2))
```

This also does not work

```r
# Does not behave as expected
data %>%
    filter(location_country != "US" | (location_country == "US" & nchar(location_admin_level_1) == 2))
```

**But** when I use base R to filter these rows, it works as expected:

```r
# Works
data[data$location_country != "US" | (data$location_country == "US" & nchar(data$location_admin_level_1) == 2), ]

# Also works
data[!(data$location_country == "US" & nchar(data$location_admin_level_1) > 2), ]
```

**Why does the base R solution work as expected but the `dplyr` solution does not?**

(Please note: I cannot create a MWE because I do not know how the filtering behavior is working, which is my question is focused on)

Comment: @akrun, I can't create a MWE because I don't know the filtering behavior to recreate it (and the data are 10 million rows). I am sorry!

Comment: I created a reproducible example and posted an answer below.  It shows the behavior with a single NA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is with existence of `NA` elements in those rows.  Base R would return an `NA` row because the `==` with `NA` returns NA while `filter` removes the `NA` in logical vector by default

```
data[!(data$location_country == "US" & nchar(data$location_admin_level_1) > 2), ]
```

Now check with `filter` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    filter(!(location_country == "US" & nchar(location_admin_level_1) > 2))
```

---

If we wanted to get the `NA` rows in `filter`, use `is.na`

```
data %>% 
   filter((!(location_country == "US" & !is.na(location_country) &
        nchar(location_admin_level_1) > 2 &
           !is.na(location_admin_level_1)))|
           is.na(location_country))
```

---

The issue is `==` returns `NA` when there is any NA

```
with(data, location_country == "US")
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE    NA
```

In `base R`, the NA in logical vector just returns an `NA` row because it is not TRUE or FALSE, while in `filter`, this gets removed by default leaving only 2 rows in the `filter` step (considering only the last expression).  To make this TRUE or FALSE, just add an `is.na`

```
with(data, location_country == "US" & !is.na(location_country))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

This would remove the `NA` rows.  But, suppose if we need the `NA` row, then the last element should be TRUE.  For that we need `|`

```
with(data, location_country == "US"|is.na(location_country))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

#### data

```
data <- data.frame(location_country = c('US', 'US', 'China', 'Canada', NA), location_admin_level_1 = c('hello', 'l', 'w', '321', '2443'))
```

Comment: if I take the number of rows where either `location_county` is NA, `location_admin_level_1` is NA, or both are NA and subtract that from the total number of rows in the data, I still do not get a data with the same dimensions as the one returned in the filtering example I thought should work

Comment: @Brigadeiro In this example, I am showing a case where the location_country is NA, and this will return NA in logical output with `==` i.e. `v1 <- c(1, 2, 3); v1 == 1` and subset gives a NA row for that.  Otherwise, we need to take care of NA with `is.na`

Comment: @Brigadeiro can you try `data %>% filter(!(location_country == "US" & !is.na(location_country) & nchar(location_admin_level_1) > 2 & !is.na(location_admin_level_1))|is.na(location_country))`

Comment: got it! Thanks so much